# I get an error "Error converting data type nvarchar to real."

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-update

The code which I have is below, can you please inform me where the issue might be so we can drop the price by warehouse ID with 7%?

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {​​​​​​​
        try
        {​​​​​​​
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(frm.cs);
            myCommand = new SqlCommand("update Inventory set Price=@Price where WarehouseCode=6", myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", "@Price * 0.7");
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Update successfully!");
            DisplayData();
            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {​​​​​​​
                myConnection.Dispose();
            }​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not assigning any value to `@Price` in the **C# code** while your `Warehouse Id` and the `Discount rate` are subject to be assigned by the end-user, I recommend your code be like this:

```
   private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {​​​​​​​
        try
        {​​​​​​​
            var discountRate = 0.07; //could be Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) or something else
            var warehouseId = 6;    //again, could be Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) or something else
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(frm.cs);
            myCommand = new SqlCommand("update Inventory set Price=Price*(1-@DiscountRate) " +
                                        "where WarehouseCode=@WarehouseId", myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiscountRate", discountRate);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WarehouseId", warehouseId);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Update successfully!");
            DisplayData();
            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {​​​​​​​
               myConnection.Dispose();
            }​​​​​​​
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }​​​​​​​
```

I would also recommend you think again about your query as it will update all products price with the same value, you may consider passing parameter `@ProductId` and your query be

```
update Inventory set Price=Price*(1-@DiscountRate) 
where WarehouseCode=@WarehouseId and ProductCode=@ProductId
```

sure that was for example.

Comment: And what if the Warehouses are 2 with two different ID's for example 6 and 1? In other words, the prices of all products in both those warehouses must change. The above worked perfectly for one of the warehouses, but the second didn't work out even after adding a second declare for WarhouseID1 = 3;

Comment: Here you may consider `WarehouseId IN (6,1)`

Comment: So your parameter be a string of Id, I do not recommend that as this will require parsing for this string

Comment: You can call the query twice or as much as you need with different IDs

Comment: I see thanks that worked too. However, when we tried to restore the 7% difference by changing the minus to plus, it didn't work:

myCommand = new SqlCommand("update Inventory set Price=Price+Price*@DiscountRate " +
                                            "where WarehouseCode IN (1,3)", myConnection);
                myConnection.Open();

Is there reason behind it?

Comment: Well, this is out of the scope of the question (this is a domain problem). Imagine your price is £50 and discount is 50% => the new price is £25, now you want add 50% again (50% of what ? of new price) which is £12.5 making the new price is £37.5 (so this is accounting domain problem). anyways you can add a table for price change history for that which is the real life commercial products do. (Price change is a transaction itself, not a simple update)

Comment: Note that I updated my answer with the formula `Price=Price*(1-@DiscountRate)`

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help, we appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you actually want a parameter. If you want to reduce the price by 7%, then you ought to do the computation directly in the query. You also need to fix the arithmetic:

```
update Inventory set Price = Price *  0.93 where WarehouseCode = 6
```

Or maybe you wanted to pass the discount as a parameter. If so:

```
update Inventory set Price = Price * (1 - @Discount) where WarehouseCode=6", myConnection
```

And you would pass value `0.07` as a value to parameter `@Discount`.

Comment: @vivaldi be VERY VERY careful when doing updates like this. if your initial attempt had worked you'd have reduced the price by 30%, not 7%.